# Cakephp: $session->flash(); gives error to me

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am quite new at cakephp despite using it several years ago in the older version of cakephp for school. Now it requires us to use $session->flash(); to display our error messages. I placed it in my view/layouts/default.ctp and this is what i got

```
Call to a member function flash() on a non-object in
C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\View\Layouts\default.ctp on line 9
```

here are my codes:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Posts';
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

public function delete($id = null) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(_('Post does not exist!', true));
            $this->Session->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        if ($this->Post->delete($id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Post deleted', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried  `$this->Session->flash()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$this->Session->flash()` in your layout, `$session->flash()` is the approach used in CakePHP 1.x.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this also refers to how $html->Link is no longer in use. We need $this->html->Link. Should have seen this coming since I called the flash with $this->Session->setFlash().

Comment: Yes, in CakePHP 2.x all helpers are used like `$this->HelperName->method()`.

Answer (score -1):

$this->Session->setFlash(__('Post deleted', true));
why using double under score you can simply use

$this->Session->setFlash('Post deleted');

Comment: That is true lol. ok small joke however, I do not believe that is the cause of the problem. the true does nothing honestly. it's just there.

Comment: __ is used for internationalization and serves a purpose there